# Windows 10 RAID - Readable from Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, raid

I've got a Win 10 machine whose hard drive (actually an M.2) is listed as RAID in the UEFI.

[Image](https://sam.nl.tab.digital/s/e4JGsHGwm6WRwLZ) of Dell Inspiron 15 5501's UEFI.

When booting from a Ubuntu 22.04 USB, the hard drive is not detected.  Is there any way linux can read this?

**Edit:** [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/963100) seems to be a partial solution that would allow me to see the drive (I'm not doing the dual boot install), except in my case I see an M.2 PCIe SSD-0 and -1.  So I'm guessing the NVME has been split in two and used for RAID that way?  Does it need to be converted to non-RAID?

Comment: Your description isn't clear. Your NVME drive is listed as "RAID" in the UEFI setup? What's the motherboard model? Then there's only one drive? So it's not a RAID anyway. You say the drive isn't detected. How do you determined that? did you try the "lsblk" command?

Comment: I think the question regarding this is that the question belongs to the Intel fake raid

Comment: @wazoox - it's a Dell Inspiron 15. There is, as far as I can tell, only one drive, though the UEFI makes it look otherwise (see the pic I added to the question). I'm not sure if that means the NVME is split in half and made RAID? Ubuntu can't see the drive. Yes, I tried lsblk, fdisk -l, and looked all over /dev/disk/...

Comment: It looks like your PC has 2 NVME SSDs from the photo you sent. And yes, I think Intel FakeRAID for NVME just isn't supported at all under Linux so you should try disabling it.